JWT with Identity .NET 8
I have a project in asp.net core with identity from .NET 8. Everything is going well, I added roles for the user (eg Admin, User) only that when I authenticate through the exitpoint at the '/login' api created by the identity token that I it returns does not contain the 3 sections and I cannot find out the user roles. If I try in the backend to find them from swagger with an exitpoint for user '/getRoles' it works.
What should I do?
I want to extract the roles from jwt in FE.

How to create a minimal reproducible example

Just for your information the /login endpoint is not supposed to return the role in plain text, it returns mainly the jwt token needed for authentification and you can configure the method that generates the token to return other things, such as the email address.

Anyway, I understand from your question that you are new to JWT in general so I will try to help.
When you authenticate successfully (email & password are correct and corresponsd to an existing account) you will get in return the jwt token which you and only you decide what information it contains and in your case the role of the user.
You can do that by more diving in claims in jwt using .net.
You can read this article as well.
